# Physically Based Shading, IBL, Half Vector, and NDotR vs NDotV

Tags: graphics, fragment-shader, lighting, pbr

I'm trying to figure out some simple concepts about image based lighting for PBR. In many documents and code, I've seen the light direction (`FragToLightDir`) being set to the reflection vector (`reflect(EyeToFragDir,Normal)`). Then they set the half vector to the mid-way point between the light and view direction: `HalfVecDir = normalize(FragToLightDir+FragToEyeDir);` But doesn't this just result in the half vector being identical to the surface normal? If so, this would mean that terms like `NDotH` are always 1.0. Is this correct?

Here is another source of confusion for me. I'm trying to implement specular cube maps from the app **Lys**, using their algorithm for generating the correct roughness value to use for mip-level sampling based on roughness (here: https://docs.knaldtech.com/doku.php?id=specular_lys#pre-convolved_cube_maps_vs_path_tracers in the section **Pre-convolved Cube Maps vs Path Tracers**). In this document, they ask us to use `NDotR` as a scalar. But what is this `NDotR` in respect to IBL? If it means `dot(Normal,ReflectDir)`, then isn't that exactly equivalent to `dot(Normal,FragToEyeDir)`? If I use either of these dot product results, the final result is too glossy at grazing angles (when compared to their more simplistic conversion using `BurleyToMipSimple()`), which makes me think I'm misunderstanding something about this process. I've tested the algorithm using `NDotH`, and it looks correct, but isn't this simply canceling out the rest of the math, since `NDotH==1.0`? Here is my very simple function to extract the mip level using their suggested logic:

```
float computeSpecularCubeMipTest(float perc_ruf)
{
    //float n_dot_r = dot( Normal, Reflect );
    float specular_power = ( 2.0 / max( EPSILON, perc_ruf*perc_ruf*perc_ruf*perc_ruf ) ) - 2.0;
    specular_power /= ( 4.0 * max( NDotR, EPSILON ) );
    return sqrt( max( EPSILON, sqrt(2.0/( specular_power + 2.0 )))) * MipScaler;
}
```

I realize this is an esoteric subject. Since everyone is using popular game engines these days, no one is forced to understand this madness! But I appreciate any advice on how to go about this.

Edit: Just to make sure I'm clear, I'm referring to pure image based lighting, with no directional lights, no spot lights, etc. Just a cube map that lights the whole scene, similar to the lighting in apps like Substance Painter and Blender's Viewport shading mode.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust That's part of my problem. There are thousands of lights. Every pixel on the environment map. How do I calculate a direction of it? For specular, we use the reflection direction to sample the environment map, which, I assume, makes the reflection vector the light direction. But then my statement becomes true, doesn't it? If we use the normal to reflect off of, then the light direction is not independent of the surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular app, but it looks like you're on the right track here. Part of the advantage of pre-convoluting the cube maps is to customize each pixel to be the light source for a particular reflection vector, so indeed NdotV is identical to NdotR as you've noticed.  The R still needs to be calculated, for the texture lookup, so it doesn't matter much which one you use for the dot.  There is no such thing as H or NdotH used for IBL lookups; those are only for point lights.

If the grazing angles look wrong, perhaps there's a Fresnel term missing somewhere? Reflections start to work differently at those angles.

For what it's worth, the glTF Sample Viewer is [using NdotV](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Viewer/blob/e47ba27a62d60ab58691a9c6af2b0fc1601f3a9f/source/Renderer/shaders/ibl.glsl#L36) for its specular IBL lookup.

Comment: The Lys app can be used to generate offline cube maps for "fake" lighting. I'm planning to try to bake my environments based on the actual rooms at some point, but not that far yet. Unfortunately, parallax correction does not look right with faked/offline maps. I really appreciate the information. There is a decent amount of PBR information out there, but very few of them talk about these types of concepts. And some of them are even using terms like NDotH as part of their setup, without explaining how or why.